# Is there a better way than lambda to filter on attributes/methods of objects?

Tags: python

Is there a better (more pythonic?) way to filter a list on attributes or methods of objects than relying on lamda functions?

```
contexts_to_display = ...
tasks = Task.objects.all()
tasks = filter(lambda t: t.matches_contexts(contexts_to_display), tasks)
tasks = filter(lambda t: not t.is_future(), tasks)
tasks = sorted(tasks, Task.compare_by_due_date)
```

Here, `matches_contexts` and `is_future` are methods of `Task`.  Should I make those free-functions to be able to use `filter(is_future, tasks)`?

Any other comment?

Comment: I think this is too specific a question to qualify as a code review.

Comment: Are you coding Django? Looks like it from the `Task.objects.all()` line.

Comment: That's part of the Django app I'm writing to learn both Python and Django, yes...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use a list comprehension:

```
contexts_to_display = ...
tasks = [t for t in Task.objects.all()
         if t.matches_contexts(contexts_to_display)
         if not t.is_future()]
tasks.sort(cmp=Task.compare_by_due_date)
```

Since you already have a list, I see no reason not to sort it directly, and that simplifies the code a bit.

The cmp keyword parameter is more of a reminder that this is 2.x code and will need to be changed to use a key in 3.x (but you can start using a key now, too):

```
import operator
tasks.sort(key=operator.attrgetter("due_date"))
# or
tasks.sort(key=lambda t: t.due_date)
```

You can combine the comprehension and sort, but this is probably less readable:

```
tasks = sorted((t for t in Task.objects.all()
                if t.matches_contexts(contexts_to_display)
                if not t.is_future()),
               cmp=Task.compare_by_due_date)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about list comprehension!  As `compare_by_due_date` specifically handles null values for the due date, I'm not sure I can use a key. But I'll find out!

Comment: @XavierNodet: Anything which can be compared by a cmp parameter can be converted (even if tediously) to a key by simply wrapping it.  With my use of the "due_date" attribute, I'm making some assumptions on how compare_by_due_date works, but if you give the code for compare_by_due_date (possibly in a SO question?), I'll try my hand at writing a key replacement for it.

Comment: Thanks! SO question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4879228/4177

Answer (score 3):

Since you are writing Django code, you don't need lambdas at all (explanation below). In other Python code, you might want to use list comprehensions, as other commenters have mentioned. `lambda`s are a powerful concept, but they are extremely crippled in Python, so you are better off with loops and comprehensions.

Now to the Django corrections.

```
tasks = Task.objects.all()
```

`tasks` is a `QuerySet`. `QuerySet`s are lazy-evaluated, i.e. the actual SQL to the database is deferred to the latest possible time. Since you are using lambdas, you actually force Django to do an expensive `SELECT * FROM ...` and filter everything manually and in-memory, instead of letting the database do its work.

```
contexts_to_display = ...
```

If those contexts are Django model instances, then you can be more efficient with the queries and fields instead of separate methods:

```
# tasks = Task.objects.all()
# tasks = filter(lambda t: t.matches_contexts(contexts_to_display), tasks)    
# tasks = filter(lambda t: not t.is_future(), tasks)
# tasks = sorted(tasks, Task.compare_by_due_date)
qs = Task.objects.filter(contexts__in=contexts_to_display, date__gt=datetime.date.today()).order_by(due_date)
tasks = list(qs)
```

The last line will cause Django to actually evaluate the `QuerySet` and thus send the SQL to the database. Therefore you might as well want to return `qs` instead of `tasks` and iterate over it in your template.

Comment: `Context` is indeed a model class, but tasks may have no context, and I want to be able to retrieve the set of all tasks that 'have a given context or no context'.  But `context__in=[c,None]` does not work...  Maybe 'no context' should actually be an instance of Context...

Comment: Similarly, the date may be null, so I can't simply filter or order on the date...

Answer (score 2):

I think lambdas are fine in this case. (Yeah, not much of a code review, but what can I say... You basically ask a yes/no question. Answer: "No". :) )

Answer (score 0):

The first lambda (calling `matches_contexts`) can't be avoided because it has to capture the `contexts_to_display`, but the `not is_future()` can be moved into a new `Task` method `can_start_now`: it's clearer (hiding the negative conditions), reusable, and this condition will most probably be more complicated in the future. Yes, [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it), I know... ;)

And because I did not need the sorting phase to return a copy of `tasks`, I used in-place sort.  By the way, the arguments are reversed between `filter(f,iterable)` and `sorted(iterable,f)`, using one just after the other seemed akward...

So the code is now:

```
class Task:
    ...
    def can_start_now(self):
        return not self.is_future()


contexts_to_display = ...
tasks = Task.objects.all()
tasks = filter(lambda t: t.matches_contexts(contexts_to_display), tasks)
tasks = filter(Task.can_start_now, tasks)
tasks.sort(Task.compare_by_due_date)
```